# MySQL versioning with Subversion

Tags: mysql, svn

Is there any integrated solution for this?

Would it work if I create a folder called mysql and dump sql there every time I do major changes?

Subversion is perfect but how do you deal with db part? Can someone please explain their workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'mysql versioning' ?

Comment: What do you want to put under version control? The data or the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)? In the first case, there are plenty of solutions for data backups that will be far more efficient than using SVN. In the later case, just generate periodically the DDL and put it under version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using simple batch files to export/import any changes to/from DB.
Just created additional folder _db with following files:

import.bat:

```
if exist c:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe goto work1

exit

:work1
C:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root --default-character-set=utf8<C:\project\_db\dbName_dc.sql
C:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -D dbName --default-character-set=utf8<C:\project\_db\dbName.sql
pause
exit
```

export.bat

```
if exist c:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe goto work1

exit

:work1
C:\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root --default-character-set=utf8 dbName>C:\project\_db\dbName.sql
C:\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -d --default-character-set=utf8 dbName>C:\project\_db\dbName_struct.sql
pause
exit
```

dbName_dc.sql

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `dbName`;
CREATE DATABASE `dbName`;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

It's not a problem to write similar files for unix like systems.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about what Scott Ambler and ThoughtWorks did about agile databases and see what you think:

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=agile+database+techniques&sprefix=agile+database%2Cstripbooks%2C131

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails uses a technique called [migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) to keep track of changes in the database schema. It creates automatically a file named `development_structure.sql` (if it does not exist you can create it for example by calling rake db:structure:dump). If you would submit or check in this file in SVN each time you make a major change, you would have stored your database changes in SVN. It contains CREATE TABLE commands like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ..
)
```